# IOS Application loader shows bundle error

Tags: ios7, loader, armv7

I have already waste 3 days "solving" this problem (actually I have tried everything i could imagine but get nothing).

While binary uploading of my application i get the following error:
ERROR ITMS-9000: "this bundle is invalid. armv7s are required to include armv7 architecture." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage).

Comment: If any of the answers has resolved the question please accept the answer. This will help others looking for the right solution. If the issue is ongoing post comments so that new posters will give additional answers. In general it's best to update all of your questions as either solved and accepted or not solved and give comments to help users to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Oh I got it, what you only need to do is to disconnect your device (**remove the cable connection between your device and system**).

Now archive it and validate. You are good to go I believe. :)

Follow These steps while uploading binary:

1. Make you Project ready to go ([Create distribution certificate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action), appstore provisioning profile with this certificate and application id of the application you are willing to upload, down load both and double click to install them)
2. Check if every thing is right, like right Icon files default files etc, and in build setting of your application you have selected your appstore provisioning profile to create you build.
3. Now unplug your device (although debug option should still remain selected to ios device) while archiving your build
4. After archiving is completed, validate your build (with same account you have created provisioning profile with), and then correct if there's some other errors, or upload the build otherwise.

Comment: My device wasn't connected! May be you understood that not the right way, but i get this error while uploading binary.

Comment: I exactly understood what u wanted to say.. coz i was getting same error at same state..

Comment: Ok, maybe i understood something not right. When should i unplug my iphone? While binary uploading? Or when? If you can, please, right step by step guide. Sorry, that i'm so stupid :)

Comment: That is the most ridiculous solution ! But it worked ! What the hell.

Comment: it worked because as Mozilla says, you had the 'Build Active Arch Only' to yes. This means that if you have a iPhone5S (arm64) connected then xCode will only include the arm64 architecture in the archive, which seems to be what the message is saying - no armv7, which is one of the architectures included in your supported architectures. Disconnecting the device means there is no active architecture so it builds them all, but it's probably better to uncheck the box so it builds all regardless of what's connected

Comment: Incredible.  Unplug iPhone, create a new archive and it validates.  Thanks.

Comment: This works and was a good indicator that the architecture settings were broken on an ancient project I had resurrected.

Comment: Disconnecting Device before building Archive fixes it. make sure the device selection are says IOS Device

Answer (score 6):

I got this error, because  arch (arm7, arm7s, arm64) + Build Active Arch Only - YES.

I did next:
 - disconnect iphone 
 - exclude arm64-arch
 - Set Build Active Arch Only - NO.

Build was successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to me was very lazy! I just lost the Universal Deployment Target (I had iPhone only for error). Fixed that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the cable and re/assigning the provisioning profile(s) etc. In the end I just removed arm64 from the list of valid architectures on the project and target files.

How much does arm64 matter anyway?