# Archive validation error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am running the GM version of Xcode 6 and am trying to validate my archive of my app. I went through iTunes Connect and filled in all the required information, yet when I try and validate I get an error saying "iTunes Store operation failed. Error Description not available." I've read somewhere that it needs to be in a state "Waiting for upload", but in the new iTunes Connect I don't know how to change it to that from "Prepare for Submission." The only thing that causes error in Connect is that I haven't selected a build, and to my knowledge (my first app) I can't do that until I validate mine. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happens to me as well, use Application Loader to submit.

Also, this link might help you when you receive error "this bundle is invalid. armv7s are required to include armv7 architecture" from Application Loader: [IOS Application loader shows bundle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211654/ios-application-loader-shows-bundle-error).

[image: Open Application Loader from Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Did you signed correctly your app for distribution ??

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Project Targets -> Code Signing` and set the `Provisioning Profile` -> `Release` to your production/distribution profile. Even setting it to `Automatic` doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, use Application Loader 2.9.1 to submit the app. Here is the link to download [Application Loader 2.9.1](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.9.1.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact same issue, and after hours looking around the internet, try everything I can but no luck. Then I figured out that... it's iTunes Connect issues!

Try to submit again and again, sometime the connection was broke, and the message "Error Description not available" appears (what' an easy-understand-message!!???!?! Why not "Connection problem, try again later")

In my case, I didn't change anything, and in the 7th try, it was submitted!

Of course the code signing is matter as well, just make sure you have a correct one for AppStore submission.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the sporadically working internet that caused the issue. Just when you wish Apple was a little more detailed about the errors they throw back at us. Could have easily said "lost internet connection" or something to that effect.